# What gear can remotely mount a Nissin i60A flash (for use as a wirelessly control flash)?

Tags: off-camera-flash, sony-alpha

I have a Nissin i60A flash with base that mates to the Sony multifunction shoe (not the classic hot shoe).  I want to be able to remotely mount it, such as on a light stand, for use as a remote slave flash.  I recently bought a Nissin Air 10s wireless flash command unit to mount on my Sony A7iii.  Digital wireless pairing was easy.  My problem is the physical mounting of the remote flash.

Has anyone figured out what gear to use for this?  I have classic hot/cold shoe adapters with 1/4-20 bases, but they don't fit Sony's new multifunction shoe.  The dimensions are different.

Answer (score 1):

Using a bracket (e.g., the [Godox S2 bracket](http://www.godox.com/EN/Products_S2_Speedlite_Bracket.html)) that secures a speedlight by its head to the stand and modifier, rather than using the foot, is a good option.